# Sistema de login em camadas com nível de acesso

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Bom dia, estou fazendo um software para conclusão de curso na escola, e eu necessito fazer um sistema de login com nível de acesso **(estou programando em camadas e utilizando o SQL SERVER 2012)**.

Vi um tutorial na net que o usuário tinha que escolher o nível de acesso quando ia fazer o login, mas queria que, ao logar como admin, seria tudo liberado e ao logar como vendedor (por exemplo) teria restrições, sendo assim não precisaria escolher o nível de acesso. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Se necessário posso mostrar os códigos do sistema de login.

Comment: Poste o código e aponte a dúvida

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, o melhor caminho, é você atribuir o nível de acesso, ao cadastrar o vendedor junto aos dados que o identificam, ou em uma tabela separada no banco de dados, ligando o que identifica o vendedor ao nível de acesso, e o programa é claro, terá que fazer essa verificação, no momento em que este usuário tentar acessar os dados, telas, etc.

A.Carlos(2c3r)